# rendering image from hdd inside razor view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have bunch on folders with images inside each of them stored on my localdisk. 
That path is referenced inside web.config so one day when move project online I can easily change this folder path.

```
<add key="MyImagesFolder" value="E:\MyImages\" />
```

I than load this value inside razor view and together with image property I want to display image using img src

```
@{
   string imagesFolder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyImagesFolder"].ToString();
   foreach (var item in @Model.Images) {
      <img src="@imagesFolder/@item.FilePath" alt="@item.Description" />
   }
}
```

image src value catched inside debug is

```
E:\\MyImages\\100/1.jpg
```

where 100 represents folder under MyImages folder.

Image does not render at all.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering html img tags with src attributes pointing to the paths to images on your server file system. Your src attributes have to contain URLs from within your web application which will provide a way to access the images through the HTTP protocol to the HTTP client (web browser).

The src attribs need to look something like:

```
http://yourwebserver/yourapp/images/1.jpg
```

or relative URLs:

```
./yourapp/images/1.jpg
```

Problem is that the web browser does not have any way to grab onto your web server file system directly

A possible solution is to put your images folder into the MVC project and render relative urls to your src attributes of the img tags.

If you just need to run your web client on the same machine as the web server your way of rendering the src attributes is also valid, but clients running outside your web server won't see the images.
If you would undergo this path, you still needed to render those src attributes as URLs with the file schema i.e.

```
file:///c:/images/1.jpg
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme